# ¿Por que obtengo el error: TypeError: can't convert complex to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, números-complejos

Quiero que el programa resuelva un sistema de ecuaciones no lineales con números complejos. Para ello he definido las variables (u1r, u1i,...) donde la r hace referencia a la parte real del número complejo y la i hace referencia a la parte imaginaria. También se pueden ver las impedáncias con las que he trabajado; también son números complejos y también las he separado por parte real y parte imaginaria.

```
import numpy as np
from spicy.optimize import fsolve

def func(z):
    u1r=z[1]
    u1i=z[2]
    u2r=z[3]   
    u2i=z[4]
    u3r=z[5]
    u3i=z[6]
    u4r=z[7]
    u4i=z[8]
    u5r=z[9]
    u5i=z[10]
    i1r=z[11]
    i1i=z[12]
    i2r=z[13]
    i2i=z[14]
    i3r=z[15]
    i3i=z[16]
    i4r=z[17]
    i4i=z[18]
    i5r=z[19]
    i5i=z[20]
    i6r=z[21]
    i6i=z[22]
    
    zpieqR = 0.00415908
    zpieqI = 0.016216639
    ypieqR = 1.16050547e-05
    ypieqI = 0.129290316

    zgR = 0.01990074
    zgI = 0.1990074

    ztreq1R = 6e-06
    ztreq1I = 0.005399999

    ytreq1R = 0.004444444
    ytreq1I = -0.4
```

A continuación he definido las ecuaciones que forman el sistema. Las ecuaciones también estan definidas como parte real y parte imaginaria.

```
    F1 = i6r*zgR - i6i*zgI - u5r + 1
    F2 = i6r*zgI + i6i*zgR - u5i + 0
    F3 = u5r*ytreq1R - u5i*ytreq1I + i6r - i5r
    F4 = u5r*ytreq1I + u5i*ytreq1R + i6i - i5i
    F5 = i5r*ztreq1R - i5i*ztreq1I + u5r - u4r
    F6 = i5r*ztreq1I + i5i*ztreq1R + u5i - u4i
    F7 = u4r*ypieqR - u4i*ypieqI + i5r - i4r
    F8 = u4r+ypieqI + u4i*ypieqR + i5i - i4i
    F9 = i4r*zpieqR - i4i*zpieqI + u4r - u3r
    F10 = i4r*zpieqI + i4i*zpieqR + u4i - u3i
    F11 = u3r*2*ypieqR - u3r*2*ypieqI + i4r - i3r
    F12 = u3r*2*ypieqI + u3i*2*ypieqR + i4i - i3i
    F13 = i3r*zpieqR - i3i*zpieqI + u3r - u3r
    F14 = i3r*zpieqI + i3i*zpieqR + u3i - u2i
    F15 = u2r*ypieqR - u2i*ypieqI + i3r - i2r
    F16 = u2r*ypieqI + u2i*ypieqR + i3i - i2i
    F17 = i2r*ztreq1R - i2i*ztreq1I + u2r - u1r
    F18 = i2r*ztreq1I + i2i*ztreq1R + u2i - u1i
    F19 = u1r*ytreq1R - u1i*ytreq1I + i2r - i1r
    F20 = u1r*ytreq1I + u1i*ytreq1R + i2i - i1i

    F21 = u1r*i1r + u1i*i1i - 1
    F22 = u1i*i1r - u1r*i1i - 0
```

Finalmente:

```
return np.array([F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21,F22], dtype=np.complex_)

z0 = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],dtype=np.complex_)
x = fsolve(func, z0)
```

En esta parte del final he intentado definir los array de manera que acepte complejos pero no me ha servido de nada.
Sigo obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

Los resultados que debería obtener son:

```
1.06796, 0.31756, 1.0840265, 0.271799,  1.082923, 0.256834, 1.077002, 
0.241957, 1.062847, 0.189058, 0.8602947, 0.2558109, 0.84711577,
0.298388, 0.88246, 0.158231, 0.948633, -0.121797, 0.979903,
-0.261046, 0.97186899, -0.2186167
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Este error viene porque la función `fsolve()` de `Scipy` no acepta numeros complejos, **solo acepta números reales**, por lo que al inicio trata de convertirlo a `float` al no ser posible, te salta el error diciendo que no puede convertir un número complejo a `float`.

Comment: Por otro lado, simplemente por si te sirve de ayuda, te recomiendo que hagas cualquier curso de Python para aprender elementos básicos del lenguaje como bucles, condicionales, listas, etc. Ya que no te llevará mucho tiempo, y sin embargo te ahorrará horas de escritura de código y corrección de errores.

Comment: Entonces, ¿cómo debo proceder para resolver mi sistema?